# Why Ubuntu isn't connecting to download.docker.com?

Tags: sudo, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The command

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

The result shows Connecting to download.docker.com initially but fails after sometime. How do I solve this?

Comment: We don't know what release you're using, so we'd currently be guessing. Are you using a release that is supported by that 3rd party resource?

Comment: Add the error message you get to the question!

Comment: it could be that you ISP could be restricting you that site. you could temporarily connect using the VPN

Answer (score 0):

The following step may help to install the docker.

Uninstall the docker first:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
gnupg \
lsb-release
```

Re-try to install:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

$ echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

$ sudo docker run hello-world
```